# Currivita - horizontal distance between bullet and content in cvlist

Tags: spacing, lists, cv, currvita

I am using `cvlist` to itemize my content as follows:

```
\begin{cvlist}{HEADING}
\item[1] blah
\item[2] blah blah
.
.
.
\end{cvlist}
```

However, the gap between the numbers (such as 1,2 etc) and the content (such blah) is very large. How can I change it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{currvita}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, we don't usually put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine the length `\cvlabelwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currvita}

\begin{document}

\begin{cvlist}{HEADING}
\item[1] blah
\item[2] blah blah
\end{cvlist}

{
\setlength\cvlabelwidth{10pt}
\begin{cvlist}{HEADING}
\item[1] blah
\item[2] blah blah
\end{cvlist}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the `currvita` documentation:

> The default width of the labels of the `cvlist` environments is equal to
>   the width of `88/8888–88/8888`, because normally in the left hand
>   column dates are typeset (and, at least in Germany, should be
>   formatted in this way).